# Accessing Google Spreadsheets with C# using Google Data API fails with Mono

Tags: c#, .net, mono, google-sheets

I'm trying to access my Google spreadsheets using the GData API. I have followed the example which looks like:

```
var service = new SpreadsheetsService("myTest");
service.setUserCredentials(username, password);
var query = new SpreadsheetQuery();
var feed = service.Query(query);
```

This should return a feed with a list of spreadsheets. However this fails with:

> Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException: Execution of request failed: http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

When I try the above link directly in my browser I'm able to download the feed, as long as I'm logged in into my Google account.

Some further information:

1. I'm not behind a firewall
2. I have checked my username (maurits.rijk at gmail.com) and password several times
3. I am using Mandriva in VirtualBox on a MacBook
4. All my code is compiled with Mono

I tried the same functionality in Java on OS-X. That code runs as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem and solution on [Google code, Issue 88](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/issues/detail?id=88) as comment 8.

In short, using

> mozroots --import --sync --quiet

solves this problem. For me it now works.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a [Mono problem](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Docs-Data-APIs/browse_thread/thread/c723b25795cfacc8/dd4bbb82af1bc9fd?lnk=gst&q=mono#dd4bbb82af1bc9fd) to me.
Could you test with fiddler to test if your call reach the server?

Comment: The Mono problem you mention seems to be pretty old (Mono 1.x) but it could still be the case. Now I only have to look for an alternative for fiddler since I'm on OS-X and Linux.

Comment: Wireshark?I saw it was old but still be the case :).This one is more recent http://groups.google.com/group/google-help-dataapi/browse_thread/thread/f2969f1d4e4ebab3/3ef5da67033235bc.

Comment: Small update: code fails both on Mandriva (inside VirtualBox) as on OS-X, using Mono.