# Adding a Contact with the Google Contacts .NET API

Tags: .net, xamarin.ios, contacts, google-api

I am using the following code to add a contact, but I get the following unhandled exception:
     Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException: Execution of request failed: http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full

```
        GDataCredentials myCred = new GDataCredentials("myusername", "mypassword");
        RequestSettings myRequestSettings = new RequestSettings("macpapa-GoogleCodeTest3-1", myCred);
        ContactsRequest myContactRequest = new ContactsRequest(myRequestSettings);

        Contact myContact = new Contact();
        myContact.Title = "Be Dazzle";
        PhoneNumber myPhoneNumber = new PhoneNumber("805-453-6688");
        myPhoneNumber.Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsGeneral;
        myPhoneNumber.Primary = true;
        myContact.Phonenumbers.Add(myPhoneNumber);

        EMail myEmail = new EMail("man@gmail.com", ContactsRelationships.IsHome);
        EMail myEmail2 = new EMail("mantest@gmail.com", ContactsRelationships.IsWork);
        myEmail.Primary = true;
        myContact.Emails.Add(myEmail);
        myContact.Emails.Add(myEmail2);

        PostalAddress postalAddress = new PostalAddress();
        postalAddress.Value = "123 somewhere lane";
        postalAddress.Primary = true;
        postalAddress.Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsHome;
        myContact.PostalAddresses.Add(postalAddress);


        Uri feedUri = new Uri(ContactsQuery.CreateContactsUri("default"));
        Contact createdContact = myContactRequest.Insert<Contact>(feedUri, myContact);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are using the wrong endpoint. http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full should be http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{your email}/full

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be a Monotouch (based on Mono) problem with Google API; see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689942/accessing-google-spreadsheets-with-c-using-google-data-api-fails-with-mono) post.

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to the fact that your contact includes an email address: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5632070/4177). Does removing the `myContact.Emails.Add` lines help?  If not, does removing all the `myContact.Xxx.Add` lines help?