# Can't connect in C# and google spreadsheet api

Tags: c#, google-sheets

Trying to access google spreadsheets using their api.  following their example, the code doesnt work, and its not obvious why.  All I'm trying to do is to connect, and I keep getting back  the same error.  This is with their code set as of 4/15/10.  Can anyone offer any suggestion on what I'm doing wrong?
CodE:

```
using System;
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Extensions;
using Google.GData.Spreadsheets;




namespace google_spreadsheet
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SpreadsheetsService myService = new SpreadsheetsService("MySpreadsheet" );
            myService.setUserCredentials("account@gmail.com", "xxxxxxx");
            string token1 = myService.QueryClientLoginToken();
            Console.WriteLine("token is {0}", token1);
            Console.ReadLine();
            SpreadsheetQuery query = new SpreadsheetQuery();
            SpreadsheetFeed feed = myService.Query(query);
           Console.WriteLine("list");
            foreach (SpreadsheetEntry entry in feed.Entries)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}", entry.Title.Text);
```

When I run this, it keeps erroring out at the myService.Query statement, with the following error:

```
Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException was unhandled
  Message=Execution of request failed: http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full
  Source=Google.GData.Client
  ResponseString=<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Not Found</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Not Found</H1>
<H2>Error 404</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>

  StackTrace:
       at Google.GData.Client.GDataRequest.Execute()
       at Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute(Int32 retryCounter)
       at Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute()
       at Google.GData.Client.Service.Query(Uri queryUri, DateTime ifModifiedSince, String etag, Int64& contentLength)
       at Google.GData.Client.Service.Query(Uri queryUri, DateTime ifModifiedSince)
       at Google.GData.Client.Service.Query(FeedQuery feedQuery)
       at Google.GData.Spreadsheets.SpreadsheetsService.Query(SpreadsheetQuery feedQuery)
       at google_spreadsheet.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Development Items\VS Projects\VS2008\google_spreadsheet\google_spreadsheet\Program.cs:line 21
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       Message=The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at Google.GData.Client.GDataRequest.Execute()
       InnerException:
```

Yet, I can take the url 
http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full
and manually type it in with my username/password, and it works fine.  Any suggestions?
thanks
rocky sanders

Comment: try to access them using SSL. it may be works.

Answer (score 0):

I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689942/accessing-google-spreadsheets-with-c-using-google-data-api-fails-with-mono/3053419#3053419) with Mono. In my case it was a problem with certificates, used by SSL.

Answer (score 0):

i believe it's becus u din't specify Uri in document query object
try this instead

```
DocumentsService service = new DocumentsService("appName");
service.Credentials = new GDataCredentials("email@gmail.com", "password");

DocumentQuery query = new DocumentQuery("http://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/-/contents");
query.Categories.Add(DocumentsListQuery.SPREADSHEETS);

var spreadsheets = service.Query(query).Entries.Cast<DocumentEntry>();
```